# Dont get imagedepth value in C using libtiff

Tags: c, libtiff

I am trying to parse a stack of tiff files using the Library libtiff5. To do so, I first need to read the the `imagelength`, `width` and `depth`. But for the `imagedepth`, I dont get any value back. The variable a in my code (below) was used to check if the function returns any value but it doesn't.

So my **question** is: how I can correctly read the `imagedepth` parameter.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include "tiffio.h"
#include "tiff.h"

int main()
{
  TIFF* tif = TIFFOpen("spots.tif", "r");
  int w, h, d;
  int a;
  printf("%d\n", d);
  TIFFGetField(tif, TIFFTAG_IMAGEWIDTH, &w);
  TIFFGetField(tif, TIFFTAG_IMAGELENGTH, &h);
  a = TIFFGetField(tif, TIFFTAG_IMAGEDEPTH, &d);

  printf("width = %d, length = %d, depth = %d\n",w, h, a );
  TIFFClose(tif);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: you  `printf("%d\n", d);` without initilizing `d`. Are you sure your program doesn't crash?

Comment: http://www.libtiff.org/man/TIFFGetField.3t.html

Comment: @Landstalker I used that print statement to debug. Before i had also an print statement after initializing to see if the value has changed but it didn't.

Comment: @tttony I did exactly what is explained there, but still it doesn't work. The problem can't be the image because I already checked wheter is a stack or not.

Comment: @Zeki normally, this should throw an exception at runtime. but my remark is independent of your main problem ...

Comment: @Zeki you probably want to check whether the opening of the tiff file succeeded. There is an error reporting variable in libtiff5 for that. Once this is checked, you could investigate further.

Comment: @Zeki try to initialize ALL your variables (w, h and d) and retry please.

Comment: @Landstalker thnx i will do that

Comment: @Heyji But then it should also give an error for the length and width. Because those values are correct.

Comment: First, understand attempting to use a variable while its value is indeterminate (not set or initialized) invokes *Undefined Behavior*. All bets are off as to how your code will behave. It can appear to work normally or SegFault or do anything in between. That there and we will go from there.

Comment: @zeki probably, but when things go wrong, you want to check all in order

Comment: @Heyji that is true I found the error function, it is TIFFError, http://www.libtiff.org/man/TIFFError.3t.html . But i don't understand how it works, can you maybe explain it to me?

Comment: Use `ret = TIFFGetFieldDefaulted(tif, TIFFTAG_IMAGEDEPTH, &d)`. Then check the returned value, e.g. `if ((ret == 0) || (d < 1)) {d = 1}`. ImageDepth is not common. It it part of the SGI extension and is not found in the TIFF6 specification. `libtiff` does not handle ImageDepth > 1. Some software falsely set ImageDepth > 1.

Comment: @cgohlke I did get ret = 1 and d =1. So if it is not found in TIFF6 specification, i cannot use libtiff to read a stack of tiff images? Which library should I use instead for reading a stacked tiff image. 

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Usually stacks of images are saved as a sequence of pages/IFDs, which libtiff can handle. Since there is no concept of depth in the TIFF specification, applications have come up with their own incompatible ways (e.g. SGI, ImageJ, STK, LSM...) or store metadata in the ImageDescription tag that describe how depth is stored in standard TIFF (e.g. OME-TIFF).

Comment: @cgohlke so if I understand correctly I should use `TIFFSetField` to define the imagedepth?

Comment: `TIFFSetField` is for writing TIFF files.

Comment: @cgohlke bu then I dont really understand what you mean